# VBA in PowerPoint without MacroRecorder

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am a pretty decent VBA programmer in Excel and now I've been asked to do some things in PowerPoint. I usually start with the recorder to see what something is named and then I go from there making my loops, if statements etc. HOWEVER, To my shock, there is no macro recorder in PowerPoint.

How do I find out what the elements on the slide are called? I have no idea how to reference anything.

Help please?

Comment: Some kind of loop reporting all element or object names to the immediate window maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Start in the PPT IDE, press F2 for the object browser and explore a bit there for starters.  Write the PPT portion of your code IN PPT, to the extent possible, then port it back to Excel.  For well-written code, this doesn't usually involve more than a few lines changed here and there.

There are several sites (Microsoft and others) that have basic code examples.  A bit of googling will provide plenty of references.

The object hierarchy is basically:

Application contains
Presentations collection, which contains
Presentation, which contains
Slides collection which contains
Slides, which contain
Shapes collection, which contains
Shapes, each of which can be accessed by name, index number or ID number.

To learn the name/etc. of a selected shape:

```
    Sub TellMeMore()
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
      MsgBox "Name: " & .Name & vbCrLf _
& "Index: " & CStr(.ZOrderPosition) & vbCrLf _
& "ID: " & CStr(.Id)
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: There is no way to click on an object and discover it's name,index number or ID number within PowerPoint? If I had that info I could probably figure out the rest.

Comment: See edited version above.  Index isn't always the best way to identify a shape as the index simply indicates the shape's position in z-order.  Name isn't entirely reliable either; while you can't create two shapes with the same name, PPT will sometimes do it for you.  It's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain.  Do you have access to Office 2003 install media?  If so, pick a host PC that doesn't require the latest and greatest Office and install Office 2003 on that PC.  PowerPoint 2003 includes a macro recorder.

The recorder will help you gain familiarity with the PPT object model and that's a plus.  On the downside, the recorder will (obviously) not show how to access PPT features added post-2003.

This [link](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Office/microsoft.public.powerpoint/2008-07/msg00845.html) provides some history regarding the PPT recorder, specifically its removal in Office 2007.